# 64 bit Linux g++ passing STRUCT btw two threads via pipe

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, alignment, pipe

I have a C++ app running on 64 bit Linux. I am planning to pass a simple struct data (without virtual function in it) from one thread to another thread ( in same process) via pipe WITHOUT any special consideration of alignment. Basically, the sending side sends the amount of sizeof(struct) bytes. And recving side cast those bytes to struct.  There is no concurrent access/atomicity concern. And there won't be any plan to pass the data to a different process or remote machine in the future.

I am positive that the code will work as expected.

However, I like to get opinions from experts of SO on my approach to see if there is any potential issues. ( as testing might not disclose them in this case).

Comment: What makes you actually think you need a pipe to do this? Also note asking for opinions is off-topic.

Comment: because the existing app was done by other developer using libuv event driven framework, the recving thread (of pipe) sends/recvs data with an external app via TCP. And the recving thread uses libvn's loop to monitor that TCP socket.  The sending thread ( of pipe) can't directly send data via that same TCP socket ( due to the libuv's restriction ). Thus, pipe seems to me a solution.

Comment: Why asking for opinions is off-topic ?

Comment: Because the policies say so. Though it's not explicitly mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it's a primary close reason.

Comment: From the [article on things that you shouldn't ask on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): "there is no actual problem to be solved” or "you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”" Also, this is very open ended with a lot of potential answers that could all be equally valid.  From the same article: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."  If you want a forum where people can brainstorm potential problems, SO isn't it.

Comment: @Becuzz Well, maybe an edge case, because using a `pipe` handle should be simply considered the wrong approach for such problem. Anyway, the question might come out _to broad_ without asking for particular code improvements/fixes.

Comment: I see your points about the open ended question. Thanks.

Comment: I think that this question is on-topic and has an answer that fits into our format.  It could easily be made clear by re-wording the last paragraph.  I would do this if it were not for a link from an active Meta question. @GoodToLearn It would improve your question *a lot* if you could update it with a short but working code demo.  I'm concerned that you're going to invoke UB but I can't tell for sure without seeing your code.  If you want a review of some working code, consider asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use a [`std::deque<MyStruct>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), and use a simple synchronisation mechanism like a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to notify the consumer thread about available data, plus a [`std:::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to make writing/reading to/from the queue thread safe.

I think this should be far more efficient than a `pipe` handle and all of the `write()`/`read()` operations coming along with such technique.

Comment: in this case, std::condition_variabl and mutex might not work for recving thread as it blocks in the default UV_loop of libnv event driving framework. ( which is similar to ( but more complex than)  select or epoll.

Comment: There is a simple trick in this situation: Use the deque as suggested but instead of using a condition variable, keep using a pipe.  However, you don't use it to send the actual data but merely write a single byte to it whenever you have added something to the deque.  You should still protect the data structure with a mutex.